# Apache Curator Shared Semaphore, how to get number of currently used leases?

Tags: java, semaphore, apache-zookeeper, distributed, apache-curator

As described in the recipe, `InterProcessSemaphoreV2` is a shared counting semaphore. I want to use it to limit number of concurrent requests (connections) that I make to a 3-rd party service from multiple instances of my java application.

I also want to keep track of the total number of simultaneous connection over my java apps but I cannot figure out if this is possible with the api of `InterProcessSemaphoreV2`.

The only method that seems to be useful is `getParticipantNodes()`

```
/**
 * Return a list of all current nodes participating in the semaphore
 *
 * @return list of nodes
 * @throws Exception ZK errors, interruptions, etc.
 */
public Collection<String> getParticipantNodes() throws Exception
{
    return client.getChildren().forPath(leasesPath);
}
```

Am I right that it should give a list of leases currently in use? Sometimes it gives collection of size 2 when the semaphore limit is only 1. Is it because updates about acquire/release come asynchronously to curator clients and clients can see small inconsistencies? Or is it wrong configuration?

Side question about performance of `InterProcessSemaphoreV2`.
What is a reasonable number of leases semaphore should take care of? Is it reasonable to have 2000 threads across 10 JVMs competing for 1000 leases in a semaphore producing around 2000 requests per second? I know curator uses zookeeper and it is also a zookeeper performance question. I understand it also depends on a hardware. But should I try it or is it definitely too many?